# The '#' in my url is not right when I use vue-router with express

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vue-router

The URL is shown as

> localhost:3000/***index#***/dashboard

but not

> localhost:3000/***index/#***/dashboard

It's kind of wired.

Here is my express code.

```
app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
    const html = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8');
    res.send(html);
});
```

And my vue-router code.

```
{
  name: 'dashboard',
  path: '/dashboard',
  component: require('../views/dashboard.vue')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `mode: 'history'` in your VueRouter

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

For more info also with express, refer to [Vue Router HTML5 history mdoe](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)

Comment: If I do so, the url will be `localhost:3000/dashboard`,but I want to keep the path `/index/`